# How subtract two aliases which are result of two cases

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling trying to subtract to results of a case within a SQL query. Do you guys can help me out?
Here is a "simplified" version of the query.

```
    SELECT        dbo.tbla.cola, dbo.tblb.colb, dbo.tblb.colc, 
CASE WHEN
                                 (SELECT        TOP 1 dstStart
                                   FROM            tblDst
                                   WHERE        tblcd.Key = dbo.tblDst.Key) >= DTimeU AND
                                 (SELECT        TOP 1 dstEnd
                                   FROM            tblDst
                                   WHERE        tblcd.Key = dbo.tblDst.Key) <= DTimeU 
THEN tblcd.ApUtc + 1 ELSE tblcd.ApUtc END AS DepDST, CASE WHEN
                                 (SELECT        TOP 1 dstStart
                                   FROM            tblDst
                                   WHERE        tblca.Key = dbo.tblDst.Key) >= ATimeU AND
                                 (SELECT        TOP 1 dstEnd
                                   FROM            tblDst
                                   WHERE        tblca.Key = dbo.tblDst.Key) <= ATimeU THEN tblca.ApUtc + 1 ELSE tblca.ApUtc END AS ArrDST
    FROM         ...
    WHERE        ...
```

How could I perform (ArrDST-DepDST) As DiffDST ?
Regards,
Dave

Comment: What's all this Select Top without any Ordered By clauses?  You can't trust SQL server to always bring records back in the same order.  Did you maybe want MIN or MAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap the query with another select :

```
SELECT t.*, t.ArrDST - t.DepDST as DiffDST
FROM (YOUR QUERY HERE) t
```

Then all the calculated columns will be available for use.